# validate string using regex in a variable

Tags: javascript, regex

This javascript code tries to validate a string using regex saved in a `pat` variable. It gives false every time even though it is expected to give true.
What am I doing wrong?  Thanks

```
isValid: (key, str) => {
  const pat = ValidationCol.findOne({'key': key}).regex; //=> ^[^@]+@[^@]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$
  return (/pat/g.test(str));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `pat` is a string, you should call `new RegExp(pat, 'g').test(str)`. If RegExp, call `pat.test(str)`. Your current code is checking if `str` contains the string `'pat'`.